# Firebase admin.database.enableLogging(true) not working

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

I'm using Firebase-admin version 5.12.0

In my `app.js` file I tried to use `admin.database.enableLogging(true);` to print log events but nothing logs.

When I googled around I found this link and this guy had the same problem. [admin.database.enableLogging(true) not working](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/230)

The thing is I can get logs when I use `firebase.database.enableLogging(true);`

**Any idea why `admin.database.enableLogging(true);` isn't working?**

App.js file:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.database.enableLogging(true) // No logs get printed
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: ...,
    privateKey: ...,
    clientEmail: ...
  }),
  databaseURL: ...,
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: { // this isn't working and I want to see if the admin logs will tell me why
       uid: "my-service-worker"
    }
});

const firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.database.enableLogging(true); // Logs print
var config = {
    apiKey: ...,
    authDomain: ...,
    databaseURL: ...,
    storageBucket: ...,
    messagingSenderId: ...
 };
 firebase.initializeApp(config);;
```

FYI the reason I want the logs from the `admin.database.enableLogging(true);` is because the `databaseAuthVariableOverride` isn't working and I want to see if I can find out why. I can't access that with the `firebase.database.enableLogging(true);` logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran this in a node script:

```
admin.database.enableLogging(true)
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) { console.log(snapshot.key); })
```

And got:

> p:0: Listen called for /50281844 default
>
> p:0: Listen on /50281844 for default
>
> p:0: {"r":25,"a":"q","b":{"p":"/50281844","h":""}}
>
> p:0: handleServerMessage d {"p":"50281844","d":{"posts":{"newPostKey":"newKeyValue"},"user-posts":{"uid":{"newPostKey":"newKeyValue"}}}}

So that looks like the standard debug logging to me. Note that I atteched a listener to get the debug logging. Without a listener, the Firebase client won't connect to the database, so there will be no database logging output.

## Update

I upgraded from version 4.0.4 to 4.2.1, which still logs for me.

I upgraded to 5.12.0, and the same code still logs (although the format looks a bit different).

Comment: Thanks for the help. The link I posted in my question that guy had the same problem. It's strange.

Comment: Ah... I might be on an older version than where the problem started. Let me upgrade.

Comment: I just tried a snippet of your code and still nothing: var usersRef = firebase.database().ref('users');
  usersRef.once("value", function(snapshot) { console.log(snapshot.key); })

Comment: I upgraded to the latest version (5.12.0), and also get logging there. What version of firebase-admin are you using?

Comment: It's in my package.json. It's the same version as you: firebase-admin": "^5.12.0"

Comment: I also installed firebase tools. If your using the same version as me I wonder could that cause the problem? $npm install -g firebase-tools --save

Comment: I'm not using the Firebase CLI, so its version shouldn't matter. How are you using it here?

Comment: Everything is in my app.js file and I run it in the cli via npm start. I'm recreating the entire npm folder again and this time I'm excluding the firebase-tools. Let's see what happens. I'm doing it now, I'll message you back in a few. Maybe something got corrupted?

Comment: nah that wasn't it. I added everything from scratch and excluded the firebase-tools module. I only added 4 modules-- "algoliasearch": "^3.27.1", "dotenv": "^5.0.1", "firebase": "^5.0.2","firebase-admin": "^5.12.0". I'm not doing anything out of the ordinary so i can't understand why it's not working. I already emailed Firebase about the databaseAuthVariableOverride not working so maybe it's all part of the same problem? I'll bring this up to them to.  When they get back to me I'll update the answer and message you with their solution. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Comment: As you can see I ignored the databaseAuthVariableOverride` aspect of your question and only focus on the logging. I recommend that you focus on one point in the interaction with support. So: either only ask about the `databaseAuthVariableOverride`, or only ask about the logging, or file two separate tickets. Mixing them in a single ticket will just make it unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I looked at your code then went back to the Firebase docs and took a wild guess and added 4 lines of code that they had. It works now. I don't understand why I needed those 4 lines for it to work but it works.  Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: thanks for the advice. I thought it was part of the same problem. What your saying makes a lot of sense as fr as confusion goes. I'll keep the issues separate when filing tickets. Good advice.

Answer (score 1):

I'm completely unsure as to why adding these lines of code got the `admin.database.enableLogging(true)` working but I just c+p these 4 lines of code [from here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) and it now it prints.

[image]

```
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("users");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Now that the `admin.database.enableLogging(true)` is now logging it prints a log that shows that the `databaseAuthVariableOverride` is working:

```
@firebase/database: p:0: from server: {"r":2,"b":{"s":"ok","d":{"auth":{"uid":"my-service-worker"},"expires":1526144418}}}
```

I still cannot get into my database but that's an entirely different issue.

Now the code looks like this:

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.database.enableLogging(true) // No logs get printed
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: ...,
    privateKey: ...,
    clientEmail: ...
  }),
  databaseURL: ...,
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: { // this is returning the uid that I defined
       uid: "my-service-worker"
    }
});

// I added these 4 lines of code here
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("users");
ref.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});

const firebase = require('firebase');
firebase.database.enableLogging(true); // Logs print
var config = {
    apiKey: ...,
    authDomain: ...,
    databaseURL: ...,
    storageBucket: ...,
    messagingSenderId: ...
 };
 firebase.initializeApp(config);;
```

Comment: Without having an active listener, your code will not connect to the database. That's why the code in my answer attached a listener.

Comment: Ohhhhhh, I thought that once the firebase-admin module was initialized it automatically listened to any/every response that was a result of the firebase-admin module. Thanks. I'll choose your answer. Can you please explain it that inside your answer so other people will understand they need a listener attached.